# How to replace multiple occurance of <br> tag in a string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need to format an email 
so need to remove multiple `<br>` tags 
I have tried this

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"[<br> ]{2,}", @"<br>", RegexOptions.None);
```

but doesn work
please assist
thanks

Comment: Provide your sample input, please. As from the first look - your regex should do its job.

Comment: <div class="WordSection1">
Heloo<br>
I need<br>
<![if !supportLists]>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<![endif]><b>A</b><br>
<![if !supportLists]>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<![endif]><b>B</b><br>
<![if !supportLists]>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<![endif]><b>C</b><br>
Please see
<b>image 1</b><br>
<br>
And
<b>image 2</b><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Thanks and Regards,<br>

Comment: You just want to remove `<br>`?  You can do this with a simple [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) call

Comment: @AnnG well, I see no "unexpected" behaviour after running your sample code on your sample input. All multiple sequential <br> tags were replaced by single one. So what is your problem?

Comment: :( doesn work.. even when I run it separately I get the formatted string. Anyway. thnx.. will keep looking

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp will not work correctly, because with `[<br> ]{2,}` you match all combinations of at least two characters <,b,r,> and space.
Use `<br>( *<br>)+` to match multiple `<br>` tags with possible spaces between.